# Passing parameter to window.onload function

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot

How can I use parameter from ModelAndView to pass it to window.onload function in javascript inside HTML file?

Controller file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/printtext")
public ModelAndView printtext() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("printtext", "showBackLink", false);
    String name = "name0";
    modelAndView.addObject("name", name);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

script in HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function (${name}) {
        document.write('text')
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `window.onload` is invoked by the browser, so I don't believe this to be possible. However if you are generating the script, then why not make it a variable directly in the script?

Comment: You can't pass parameters. Refer to the value in the body of the function.

Comment: Not on plain HTML. If you have JSP, you can do something like <script>var myObj =<c:out value="${myObj}"/>........</script>

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting it in the wrong place.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var serverData = "${name}";
window.onload = function () {
    document.write(serverData); // don't actually use document.write()
}
</script>
```

Comment: But HTML does not recognize this "${name}". It treats that as a string. Do I have to create JSP to use it (I'd like to avoid it)?

Comment: I've never used spring; I was assuming the server parses the HTML and inserts the added objects. You have to either use a templating engine of some kind, or load data directly using AJAX.